# Docker-compose equivalent for docker run --rm -volume E:/Randomfolder

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im trying to run a linux docker container which gets access to my local E: disk on the windows server where docker is running. Im doing this via docker-compose up. I was looking for a way to give my container access to the file system where its hosted.

In docker i would do this: docker run --rm -v "E:/Randomfolder"

Comment: I'm not sure what version you're running, but you should just be able to use the `volume` property: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use volumes directive in docker-compose file:

```
  volumes:
  - E:Randomfolder
```